# Starting Grounded Mode+ on The Last of Us

Tags: ps3, the-last-of-us

Is there any way to start Grounded Mode Plus without completing Grounded Mode first?

I really don't want to play the entire game twice in Grounded Mode. I heard that if you complete Normal Mode then you can play Grounded Mode Plus, but I'm not sure how this works...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some research I came up with a answer:

1. You will need to complete the main game on any difficulty;
2. When you are at the Main Menu, choose the option at the top that should say *Continue New Game Plus*. (If you need too, load up a save for NG+ then quit out.) Start on PROLOGUE;
3. At the end of the PROLOGUE, you will be with Tess, save and quit. Go back to the main menu;
4. Now chapter select and pick PROLOGUE, but choose GROUNDED;
5. You should now be on GROUNDED +.

   - To make sure you are on GROUNDED +. Hit *Start* > *Options* > *Game* and make sure it says "Grounded". Then go to *Start* > *Load Game* > and wait for the save file to pop up. It should say New Game Plus.
   - Another way to verify, is wait until you are with Tess and get your backpack and gun. Hit button *Select* and button *R1* to see if you are upgraded.

Source: [PSN Profiles](http://psnprofiles.com/forums/topic/33828-grounded-mode/)